# x mod 2 = x mod p, where p odd prime. What can be said about x and p.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

What sort of solutions do we get. What can be said about x and the odd prime p?
Any insights?

Comment: were you looking for a name to call those numbers ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. It's good if you read community guidelines.  If you talk about some expressions with symbols (equations and so on) just write it in a math environment. Try to write your question as precisely  as possible and don't forget to add your thoughts about the question (what you have tried, when solving the problem yourself. )

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there is not much to be said if I understand your question correctly.

Counting modulo two is just determining whether the number is even or odd.

So if we have $x \equiv 1 \pmod{2} $ then it tells it is odd. Now $x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, so $x$ has to be of form $x=kp+1$ where $k$ is some integer. But we also know that $x$ is odd, so we conclude that $k$ is even.

Similarly you discuss for $x$ even (i.e. $x \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$).

In conclusion: you have some information about $x$ but now information about $p$.